# NSIS ZipDLL plugin not working

Tags: installation, zip, nsis

I'm trying to do a simple installer, I want to copy a zip file to my install directory, and unzip it's contents there, but right now it only copies my zip, and doesn't unzip it.

Here is my code

```
;--------------------------------
;Include Modern UI
        !include "MUI2.nsh"
;--------------------------------
;General
    Name "App"  ; Name of the app to install
    OutFile "setup.exe" ; Name of the app installer
    InstallDir "c:\app\"    ; App install directory (default C:)
    InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\App" "" ; Get installation folder from registry if available
    RequestExecutionLevel user ;Request application privileges for Windows Vista
    Caption "App"
;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings
  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
;--------------------------------
;Language Selection Dialog Settings
    ;Remember the installer language
    !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "HKCU" 
    !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\App" 
    !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Language"
;--------------------------------
;Pages
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
  ;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  ;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  ;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  ;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
;--------------------------------
;Languages
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"   ; Default English
    !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish" ; Spanish
;--------------------------------
; ZIP Handling
    !include "ZipDLL.nsh"
;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections
Section "XAMPP" App
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    File App.zip
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\App" "" $INSTDIR   ; Store installation folder
  ; WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"               ; Create uninstaller
    ; !insertmacro ZIPDLL_EXTRACT "$INSTDIR\App.zip" "$INSTDIR" "<ALL>"
    !insertmacro ZIPDLL_EXTRACT "C:\App\App.zip" "c:\App\" "<ALL>"
SectionEnd
;--------------------------------
;Descriptions
  ;Language strings
  LangString DESC_App ${LANG_ENGLISH} "The server modules necesary to install app."
    LangString DESC_App ${LANG_SPANISH} "Los modulos del servidor necesarios para instalar app"

  ;Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${App} $(DESC_App)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END
;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Sections
;Section "Uninstall"
;  ;ADD YOUR OWN FILES HERE...
;  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
;  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
;  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\App"
;SectionEnd
;--------------------------------
;Installer Functions
    Function .onInit
        !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
    FunctionEnd
;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Functions
;   Function un.onInit
;       !insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
;   FunctionEnd
;--------------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the portable version of NSIS to compile my installer. Then I installed the full version on my PC, and the same script now works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work either when setting RequestExecutionLevel to admin? assuming you're installing to program files, you will have to do that (though it wouldn't extract the zip to that folder either). did you make sure the file is in place?

Comment: The file is in place, the installer copies it to the installation dir (C:\App\), but it's not unziping.

Comment: hm, just tested your script and it works just fine, so maybe the problem is not in your code?

Comment: I was using the portable version of NSIS to compile my installer. I installed NSIS on my pc, used the exact same script and it appears that now it is working. Maybe there's something wrong with the portable NSIS app. Wow, why didn't I did that earlier!